# SSRS importer in C# 4.0, move reports from one server to another w/o changing format

Tags: c#-4.0, reporting-services

yes, i know about File.Copy(...), but is there a web service method that can do the same thing? i am also worried about credentials needed to access the server. the inputs are to be the report filepath and the url to the server i want to move the report to WITHOUT CHANGING THE FORMAT. i have been looking at the web service ReportService2005 but not so sure it will work. other web services i have available are: ReportExecution2005, ReportingServices, ReportService, and ReportService2006. i would like to stay away from using rs.exe as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Determine filename without extension (used as name in SSRS)
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(FileSystemPath);
string fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileInfo.FullName);
try
{
    // Determine filecontents
    Byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(fileInfo.FullName);

    // Publish report
    rsService.Warning[] warnings = this.rs.CreateReport(fileNameWithoutExtension, this.SSRSFolder, true, fileContents, null);

    if (warnings != null)
    {
       foreach (rsService.Warning warning in warnings)
       {
          //Log warnings
       }
    }
}
catch
{
   //handle error
}
```